# fork-like thread in C++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have similar requirements with this SO question: [fork-like stack copying threads in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862782/fork-like-stack-copying-threads-in-c) .
That is:

1. Stack copying variables.
2. Continue the parent execution point.
3. Cross platforms/systems.

Intel's TBB clearly violate the third requirement. Is it possible to reach my goal with standard C++11 or proper third-party libraries(e.g. Boost)?

Comment: Is the complaint the same as in that question, i.e. fork() being too expensive? If that's the case, maybe try to use the clone() system call directly. You get to control what's shared or copied at a much finer level.

^ that is, of course, if by "cross system", you mean "linux"

Comment: @user3109672 the POSIX solutions(i.e. clone syscall) you provided does not meet the requirement of cross platforms, which is, under some circumstance, cross OS.

Comment: So, you want the thread when running to have the copies of all the variables in the stack at the time when the thread was created ? If yes, then wont instantiating a thread with 'copy-capturing' lambda help ? `thread([=]() { //use viariable})`

Comment: @Arunmu Yes that meet the first requirement but what about the second? I think second one is the most tricky.